# Determining Types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Let's say I'm creating a data type in haskell, and this data type accepts multiple constructors. Is there an easy way to determine later in my code which one it was created as?

EDIT:

Example, I'm using the dataType

```
data LogicValue =  CloseAnd (Int, Int) (Int, Int)
            | CloseXor (Int, Int) (Int, Int)
            | FarAnd LogicValue LogicValue 
            | FarXor LogicValue LogicValue
```

Is there an easy way to determine if something is a CloseAnd for instance?

Comment: You both answered within 20 seconds of each other.. I wish I could mark you both as correct. Marking leftaroundabout, because they were first by a hair.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course, just pattern-match on the constructor name!

```
f :: LogicValue -> Ret
f (CloseAnd a b) = ...
f (CloseXor a b) = ...
```

The same can of course be done with a `case` switch.

---

Since this question keeps appearing in my notifications box (my answer having votes it, if I'm honest, probably doesn't quite deserve) I'd like to add that your problem doesn't have anything to do with "determining types". Different constructors of a `data` **all have the same result type**, namely `LogicValue`. You're probably thinking about "subtypes" `CloseAnd`, `CloseXor`..., like you could have in an OO language. Haskell variant types have some similarities to an OO class hierarchy, but they're still a different concept.

Answer (score 5):

You use pattern matching for that:

```
logictype :: LogicValue -> [Char]
logictype (CloseAnd _ _) = "It is a closeAnd."
logictype (CloseXor _ _) = "It is a closeXor."
logictype (FarAnd _ _)   = "It is a FarAnd."
logictype (FarXor _ _)   = "It is a FarXor."
```

You can also match the parameters:

```
logictype (CloseAnd (a,b) (c,d)) = "it is a closeAnd with parameters " ++ show [a,b,c,d]
```